# can't display data in the table (angular 9)

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gduqL.png)`     Hi ! i am using angular 9.1.7 , the code works correctly , and i succeed to get data from base , but i can't display them in the html table , i don't understand the source of this. you find below some source code , and thank you in advance

`

```js
==>Interface package:
     public universites:Universite[];
      public universitesall:Universite[];
      public mot_cle:string="";
      constructor(private universitesService:UniversitesService) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.Afficheruniversites();
      }
      Afficheruniversites()`enter code here`
      {
        this.universitesService.tous_universites().subscribe(data=>{
          this.universites=data;
          this.universitesall=data;
          console.log(data);
        },err=>{console.log(err);
      })
      }
      

      ==>> model
      export class Universite {
        code_UNV:number
        nom_UNV:String
        adresse_site_UNV:String

        constructor(Code_uni:number, Nom_uni:String,Adr:String)
        {
            this.code_UNV=Code_uni;
            this.nom_UNV=Nom_uni;
            this.adresse_site_UNV=Adr;
        }
    }
```

```html
==>> Html 
     <table *ngIf="universites" class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Code
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Nom
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Adresse
                        </th><th></th>
                        <tr *ngFor="let c of universites">
                            <td>
                                {{c.code_UNV}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{c.nom_UNV}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{c.adresse_site_UNV}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: what is console.log(data) prniting?

Comment: it shows the data i get from base in console (for test)

Comment: i added an image showing the problem

Comment: just change your html to what pbmahadik gave below.

Comment: i have given you html below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need check your data, in attach image, it console log as codeUNV not code_UNV as your defined.

[image]

I tried reproduce your code, it work.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1tr7we

Comment: thank you , it works now ,  codeUNV, nomUNV and adresseSite resolves the problem

Answer (score 1):

Can you please close your first tr tag in html ? Hopefully this will work

```
<table *ngIf="universites" class="table table-striped"> 
<tr> 
<th> Code </th> 
<th> Nom </th> 
<th> Adresse </th>
</tr> 
<tr *ngFor="let c of universites"> <td> {{c.code_UNV}} </td> <td> {{c.nom_UNV}} </td> <td> {{c.adresse_site_UNV}} </td> </tr> </table>
```

Comment: hi , thank you for replying, i colse the tag , but still same problem , i succed to show the data i get in console (json form), but with an empty table

Answer (score 0):

```
   <table *ngIf="universites" class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Code
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Nom
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Adresse
                        </th><th></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr *ngFor="let c of universites">
                            <td>
                                {{c.codeUNV}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{c.nomUNV}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{c.adresseSite}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: thank you very much !, it works now , your answered helped me